Error connecting to internet from kubernetes POD
I am running a kubernetes pod in which i am running a python script which connects to some external API's gets results and pushes the data to some data storage service when I run the container outside the pod it works fine it able to get the data from api and push it to storage service . The moment I run it from kubernetes pod it fails with some connectivity issue . Below are the logs
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name request-latency
DEBUG:kafka.cluster:Updated cluster metadata to ClusterMetadata(brokers: 3, topics: 4, groups: 0)
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.bytes-sent
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.bytes-received
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.latency
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 None]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]>: connecting to 10.1.1.198:9092 [('10.1.1.198', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:Probing node bootstrap-0 broker version
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request ApiVersionRequest_v0()
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Request 1: ApiVersionRequest_v0()
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v0(topics=[])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Request 2: MetadataRequest_v0(topics=[])
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 1
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response ApiVersionResponse_v0
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Response 1 (101.78351402282715 ms): ApiVersionResponse_v0(error_code=0, api_versions=[(api_key=0, min_version=0, max_version=9), (api_key=1, min_version=0, max_version=15), (api_key=2, min_version=0, max_version=8), (api_key=3, min_version=0, max_version=12), (api_key=4, min_version=0, max_version=7), (api_key=5, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=6, min_version=0, max_version=8), (api_key=7, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=8, min_version=0, max_version=8), (api_key=9, min_version=0, max_version=8), (api_key=10, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=11, min_version=0, max_version=9), (api_key=12, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=13, min_version=0, max_version=5), (api_key=14, min_version=0, max_version=5), (api_key=15, min_version=0, max_version=5), (api_key=16, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=17, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=18, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=19, min_version=0, max_version=7), (api_key=20, min_version=0, max_version=6), (api_key=21, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=22, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=23, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=24, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=25, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=26, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=27, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=28, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=29, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=30, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=31, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=32, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=33, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=34, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=35, min_version=0, max_version=4), (api_key=36, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=37, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=38, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=39, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=40, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=41, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=42, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=43, min_version=0, max_version=2), (api_key=44, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=45, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=46, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=47, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=48, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=49, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=50, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=51, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=56, min_version=0, max_version=3), (api_key=57, min_version=0, max_version=1), (api_key=58, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=60, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=61, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=65, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=66, min_version=0, max_version=0), (api_key=67, min_version=0, max_version=0)])
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 2
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response MetadataResponse_v0
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Response 2 (2.768278121948242 ms): MetadataResponse_v0(brokers=[(node_id=2, host='10.1.1.199', port=9092), (node_id=3, host='10.1.1.201', port=9092), (node_id=1, host='10.1.1.198', port=9092)], topics=[(error_code=0, topic='avro_topic', partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3])]), (error_code=0, topic='gsuite_test_topic', partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3])]), (error_code=0, topic='test_topic', partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3]), (error_code=0, partition=1, leader=1, replicas=[1], isr=[1])]), (error_code=0, topic='__consumer_offsets', partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=10, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=20, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=40, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=30, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=9, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=11, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=31, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=39, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=13, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=18, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=22, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=8, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=32, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=43, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=29, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=34, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=1, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=6, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=41, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=27, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=48, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=5, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=15, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=35, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=25, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=46, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=26, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=36, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=44, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=16, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=37, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=17, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=45, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=3, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=24, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=38, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=33, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=23, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=28, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=2, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=12, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=19, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=14, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=4, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=47, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=49, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=42, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=7, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=21, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2])])])
INFO:kafka.conn:Broker version identified as 2.5.0
INFO:kafka.conn:Set configuration api_version=(2, 5, 0) to skip auto check_version requests on startup
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name batch-size
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name compression-rate
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name queue-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name records-per-request
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-retries
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name errors
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-size-max
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=NULL) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=NULL)
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Request 3: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=NULL)
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Kafka producer started
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 3
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response MetadataResponse_v1
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.1.1.198:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.1.198', 9092)]> Response 3 (2.1560192108154297 ms): MetadataResponse_v1(brokers=[(node_id=2, host='10.1.1.199', port=9092, rack=None), (node_id=3, host='10.1.1.201', port=9092, rack=None), (node_id=1, host='10.1.1.198', port=9092, rack=None)], controller_id=1, topics=[(error_code=0, topic='avro_topic', is_internal=False, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3])]), (error_code=0, topic='gsuite_test_topic', is_internal=False, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3])]), (error_code=0, topic='test_topic', is_internal=False, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3]), (error_code=0, partition=1, leader=1, replicas=[1], isr=[1])]), (error_code=0, topic='__consumer_offsets', is_internal=True, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=10, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=20, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=40, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=30, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=9, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=11, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=31, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=39, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=13, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=18, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=22, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=8, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=32, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=43, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=29, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=34, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=1, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=6, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=41, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=27, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=48, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=5, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=15, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=35, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=25, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=46, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=26, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=36, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=44, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=16, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=37, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=17, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=45, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=3, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=24, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=38, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=33, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=23, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=28, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=2, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=12, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=19, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=14, leader=3, replicas=[3, 1, 2], isr=[3, 1, 2]), (error_code=0, partition=4, leader=2, replicas=[2, 1, 3], isr=[2, 1, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=47, leader=3, replicas=[3, 2, 1], isr=[3, 2, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=49, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=42, leader=1, replicas=[1, 2, 3], isr=[1, 2, 3]), (error_code=0, partition=7, leader=2, replicas=[2, 3, 1], isr=[2, 3, 1]), (error_code=0, partition=21, leader=1, replicas=[1, 3, 2], isr=[1, 3, 2])])])
DEBUG:kafka.cluster:Updated cluster metadata to ClusterMetadata(brokers: 3, topics: 4, groups: 0)
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d76df9f-b9c0-483e-8f19-2b3d8ce31921/oauth2/v2.0/token'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.17.1 Python/3.10.12 (Linux-4.19.0-26-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.35)'
A body is sent with the request
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d76df9f-b9c0-483e-8f19-2b3d8ce31921/oauth2/v2.0/token'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.17.1 Python/3.10.12 (Linux-4.19.0-26-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.35)'
A body is sent with the request
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d76df9f-b9c0-483e-8f19-2b3d8ce31921/oauth2/v2.0/token'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.17.1 Python/3.10.12 (Linux-4.19.0-26-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.35)'
A body is sent with the request
WARNING:azure.identity.aio._internal.get_token_mixin:ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<TCPConnector._resolve_host_with_throttle() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:904> cb=[shield.<locals>._inner_done_callback() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:847]> got Future <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<Event.wait() running at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/locks.py:201>> attached to a different loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/get_token_mixin.py", line 93, in get_token
    token = await self._request_token(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_credentials/client_secret.py", line 67, in _request_token
    return await self._client.obtain_token_by_client_secret(scopes, self._secret, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/aad_client.py", line 49, in obtain_token_by_client_secret
    return await self._run_pipeline(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/aad_client.py", line 93, in _run_pipeline
    response = await self._pipeline.run(request, retry_on_methods=self._POST, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 219, in run
    return await first_node.send(pipeline_request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry_async.py", line 180, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 104, in send
    await self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_aiohttp.py", line 303, in send
    result = await self.session.request(  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1203, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await self._resolve_host(host, port, traces=traces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 880, in _resolve_host
    return await asyncio.shield(resolved_host_task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 904, in _resolve_host_with_throttle
    await event.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/locks.py", line 29, in wait
    val = await waiter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<TCPConnector._resolve_host_with_throttle() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:904> cb=[shield.<locals>._inner_done_callback() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:847]> got Future <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<Event.wait() running at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/locks.py:201>> attached to a different loop
WARNING:azure.identity.aio._internal.get_token_mixin:ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<TCPConnector._resolve_host_with_throttle() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:917> cb=[shield.<locals>._inner_done_callback() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:847]> got Future <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:385]> attached to a different loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/get_token_mixin.py", line 93, in get_token
    token = await self._request_token(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_credentials/client_secret.py", line 67, in _request_token
    return await self._client.obtain_token_by_client_secret(scopes, self._secret, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/aad_client.py", line 49, in obtain_token_by_client_secret
    return await self._run_pipeline(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/identity/aio/_internal/aad_client.py", line 93, in _run_pipeline
    response = await self._pipeline.run(request, retry_on_methods=self._POST, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 219, in run
    return await first_node.send(pipeline_request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry_async.py", line 180, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 68, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base_async.py", line 104, in send
    await self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_aiohttp.py", line 303, in send
    result = await self.session.request(  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1203, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await self._resolve_host(host, port, traces=traces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 880, in _resolve_host
    return await asyncio.shield(resolved_host_task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 917, in _resolve_host_with_throttle
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 33, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 863, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=

Deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prod-O365-deployment
  labels:
    app: prod-O365-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:prod-O365-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prod-O365-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prod-O365-app
        image: 786786786raees/email1_monitoring:51

I am using calico network for the pods
